# using a config file using environment variable in camel spring boot project

Tags: xml, docker, apache-camel

I am working on a camel spring boot project where in the `camelcontext.xml` I am using a config file through the environment variable.

The code is as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
.
.
.
    <bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder"
        class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="file:${cfgfilepath}config.cfg" />
        <property name="parser" ref="jasypt" />
    </bean>
.
.
// remaining code
```

Now, when I run this project normally in my **Windows** machine, it is running successfully. But when I try to create a **docker container**, I am not able to get this `cfg` file.

I tried these things -

- Hard-coded the path as
  `C:/Users/camelproject/src/main/resources/config.cfg` and
  `C:\Users\camelproject\src\main\resources\config.cfg` *(I'm not sure
  the structure for a file path)*
- Created an `ENV` in `Dockerfile` as - `ENV cfgfilepath C:/Users/camelproject/src/main/resources/config.cfg` and `ENV cfgfilepath C:\Users\camelproject\src\main\resources\config.cfg` and `ENV cfgfilepath C://Users//camelproject//src//main//resources//config.cfg` and then use the variable as in the above code.
- Passed `C:/Users/camelproject/src/main/resources/config.cfg` as value in `-e` option while running the `docker run` command. ie. `docker run -e cfgfilepath=C:/Users/camelproject/src/main/resources/config.cfg`
- In the `Dockerfile` I did - `COPY target/config.cfg /app/config/config.cfg` and then in `camelContext.xml` I replaced with `value="file:/app/config/config.cfg` but that too returned the below error.

Where am I going wrong? The error I get -

> FileNotFoundException:
>   C:/Users/camelproject/src/main/resources/config.cfg (No such file or
>   directory)

or *(when I use enviroment variable)*

> FileNotFoundException:
>   ${cfgfilepath}config.cfg (No such file or
>   directory)

The `Dockerfile` -

```
FROM java:openjdk-8-jre-alpine 

WORKDIR /app

VOLUME /app /var/config

# add directly the jar
ADD target/camelproject-jar-with-dependencies.jar /app.jar
COPY target/config.cfg /app/config/config.cfg

# ENV cfgfilepath /app/config/
# ENV cfgfilepath C:/Users/camelproject/src/main/resources/
ENV cfgfilepath C://Users//camelproject//src//main//resources//

RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'

CMD echo "The application will start in few seconds..." && \
    java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

Comment: Try using `file:${env:cfgfilepath}`. Perhaps ENV variables in Docker are viewed as OS ENV variables rather than JVM. Also, if you put your config file directly under `/resources` you should be able to find it by using the classpath instead just by setting `<property name="location" value="config.cfg" />`.

Comment: Try to pass your property via jvm parameter like -Dcfgfilepath=yourpath

Comment: @noMad17 the config file was already in `/resources` and by changing the code to `<property name="location" value="config.cfg"` I am able to get the config file.
But after this, I am getting another error, which is explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881040/use-a-file-in-docker-containers-windows

Comment: @RicardoZanini hey, thanks for your comment but the issue got solved by noMad17's suggestion.

Comment: Could you guys wrap this solution into a answer? :)