# use a file in docker containers - windows

Tags: docker, keystore, apache-servicemix

This is a two part question.

1) In windows, can a folder form any drive apart from C drive be shared? While surfing the internet, I found that by default only C drive can be mounted in docker containers. *(Users folder of C drive)*

2) Now coming to the main part - I am working on a camel project where I am using a config file. In this config file, I am using two parameters for **Servicemix** keystore files. Now previously the keystores are located at path - `D:\sandboxes\apache-servicemix-7.0.0.M3\apache-servicemix-7.0.0.M3\etc\keystores`.

I tried giving this path and it resulted in error -

> File not found

I copied the keystores folder to `C:\Users` and then gave the path `C:\Users\keystores` but the error remained the same.

Now while running the `docker run` command, I am already mapping the volume where my camel project is - `docker run -v //C/Users/camelproject:/app ...`

So, is it possible to mount different folders from two drives using `-v` option? Also what shall I do to use these keystore files in my project?

**Edit 1 -**

Okay, so I did the following things -

- Copied the keystores folder to my camel project in C drive. The path is now - `C:/Users/camelproject/src/main/resources/keystores`
- Used this path in the config file as `keyStore=C:/Users/camelproject/src/main/resources/keystores/client.ks`
- I am using this file in my `camelcontext.xml` as - `<property name="keystore" value="${keyStore}" />`
- I mounted the folders as `docker run -v //C/Users/camelproject:/app -v //C/Users/camelproject/src/main/resources:/app/config ...` and then in the config file alternatively gave both, Windows and container path, as the value but for both it gave the same error.

So basically the file should be found but the error is coming.

Comment: `-v` mounts folders, not drives. You don't *want* your container to have access to a drive for obvious security and isolation reasons.  Any folder can be mounted by by default it appears under C: inside the container. After all, you have to define additional drives if you want to use them. Nothing prevents you from writing `-v k:/data/:c:/data/` to map a folder in your K: drive to a folder in the container's C: drive

Comment: yeah I meant folder inside D drive, I've edited the question appropriately.

Comment: So where is the folder on your host? Why not map it to `C:\keystores` internally and use `C:\keystores` instead of `D:\sandboxes\...`? Or create a separate folder, just for your container and map it to `C:\keystores` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sounds good, let me try that out

Comment: hey @PanagiotisKanavos. So I diid this -
Copied the `keystores` folder to my project under `src > main > resources` and then in the `config` file gave the path of the keystores as - `keyStore=C:/Users/camelproject/src/main/resources/keystores/client.ks` and then use t in `camelcontext.xml` as `<property name="keystore" value="file:${keyStore}" />`.
But the error remains the same

Comment: hey @PanagiotisKanavos, I am storing the file in the same project but container still is not able to find the file.

Answer (score 0):

> So, is it possible to mount two drives using -v option?

No this is not possible you need to use multiple -v option for different directories.

Docker with windows volume mounting has some issues it will not allow " - " option in path. ( for example C:/camel-project )

And always use / slash not .

More related discussion is been done here.
https://forums.docker.com/t/volume-mounts-in-windows-does-not-work/10693/7